# Alternative for 'enter' key in python interpreter?

Tags: python, linux, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, interpreter

Recently my <kbd>Enter</kbd> key stopped working. For sure it's a hardware problem!. However I managed so many days without <kbd>Enter</kbd> key by using the alternatives <kbd>ctrl + j</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl + m</kbd> .Running python programs was fine as I would run the script by saving it in a file. Now that I need to give commandline values **I have to press *enter*** for it to be accepted in the **IDLE Interpreter**. While typing this too I can't press <kbd>enter</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl + j</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl + m</kbd>.

But how did I do this? (This newline?) I copied a **empty newline** from another file. Even this doesn't work in the interpreter. Someone help any way to enter values in python **IDLE Interpreter** without actually using `enter` key.

One good alternative would be to use the `cmd` or `terminal` and using the command line `python script.py`. And then using <kbd>ctrl+m</kbd> as this works there.

But I miss the python interpreter. Any alternatives any suggestion?

**Ofcourse onscreen keyboard is an option but I'm looking for any key alternatives to `enter` in python Interpreter.** Is that even possible?

Comment: If you are on Windows, I would suggest you to use an AutoHotKey script to rebind your enter key, at least you know it will work everywhere

Comment: My keyboard has a second Enter key on its numeric keypad. If yours doesn't, the suggestion of using [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) is a good one.

Comment: ok will look into that @martineau

Comment: In IDLE's options, you can change the key binding for `newline-and-indent`. For example, make it `<Control-Key-m> <Control-Key-M> <Key-Return> <Key-KP_Enter>`. There's also `plain-newline-and-indent`, which should already be `<Control-Key-j> <Control-Key-J>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, IDLE has an Option / Configure IDLE menu which allows you to remap almost any action to a key combination. The *newline and indent* action is by default mapped to <kbd>Key Return</kbd> and <kbd>Num Keypad Return</kbd>, while <kbd>Ctrl J</kbd> is used for *plain newline and indent*. But it is easy to change this mapping configuration.